# angular 2: assets not loaded when deployed in subdirectory

Tags: angular, deployment, assets, subdirectory

I'm trying to deploy my angular 2 app in a sub directory: I searched SO and google, and found I've to build it with the following command:

```
ng build -prod --base-href /angular-test --deploy-url /angular-test
```

but it's still not loading the assets.

Under networks in inspect, call to assets are going with:

```
/assets/i18n/en.json
```

whereas it should be

```
/angular-test/assets/i18n/en.json
```

Do I need to do something else? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. but given solution is not working though. is there any other fix I can do to my code?

Comment: See the comments from accepted answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the examples I've seen are of this format:

```
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
```

So I would think you would need this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /angular-test/
```

( With a trailing slash )

Comment: still not working. this is how I put it -  ng build -prod --base-href /angular-test/ --deploy-url /angular-test/

Comment: if you need any additional details, please do tell

Comment: Have you seen the discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4517

Comment: I've it working now. Problem was i added '/../../assets' in my htmls. I replace it with just '/assests'. thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: the problem of base href is that will affect every url and aas well the angular routing

Answer (score 4):

replace `../../../assets/images/example.jpg` to `./assets/images/example.jpg` then it worked for me.